# How do I delete these movies from my iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, ios, storage

I tried swiping it, but my movies for some reason show up vertical. So swiping, doesn't work. I can't seem to find a way to get it off my phone and it's taking up more then half of my storage! I need help a soon as possible

Answer (score 1):

You can connect it to iTunes and remove the sync option under movies and sync your iPhone 4. This should remove the existing content from the iPhone and clear up space.